# Why is my image being displayed sidewards?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, bitmap

Im following a tutorial on Youtube on taking Photo From Camera Without Losing The Quality Of The Image

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYRXXOM3aGI

Everything is working as intented but the result at the end displays incorrectly rotated to the left and no matter what I do I cannot fix it. I seen a guy on the youtube comments saying he was having the same issue but his method didnt fix my issue. I cannot find the area or function within Android Studio to alter the rotation of the result displayed on screen.

[Displaying Result on Screen after activity][1].

Sorry if I am not clear enough. Im an ok Java dev just beginning in Android Studio. My question is, is there a function I can use to rotate the desired output of a newly taken and displayed Bitmap image.

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9nqS.png![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9nqS.png!%5B) image tree meant to be facing upwards not sidewards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvKXh.jpg)

Comment: https://snipboard.io/UE5xRW.jpg

It is meant to be like this, only my displayed image is rotated 90 degrees to the left.

Comment: What do you mean by rotated to the left?

Comment: I edited my post and added another picture to highlight my issue. I took a picture using the app of a tree. Now the tree is rotated to the left

Answer (score 0):

For what it seems your device's camera may be applying an EXIF rotation angle to the output photo, instead of rotating the actual image pixels, which is valid and something done by many devices.

The [Bitmapfactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory) class does not perform any type **EXIF rotations / transformations** at all. You need to perform them yourself.

Use the [ExifInterface](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/exifinterface) class to get the rotation information. You should use the AndroidX variant instead of the deprecated framework one.

So what you must do is to get the image's EXIF, and if found in the **TAG_ORIENTATION** a value other than **ORIENTATION_NORMAL**, then you must rotate the image according to the EXIF angle. This operation will require to create a new bitmap, therefore in order to avoid a potential [OutOfMemoryError](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError), use some of the tips provided in this [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap).

**Another simpler alternative**, is to get the EXIF angle, and apply an **image rotation matrix** to the ImageView according to such angle, so no need to modify the image file at all. Notice that the ImageView has a [matrix scale type](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType#MATRIX) which can be used in such scenarios.

Comment: Thank you this is a very detailed answer. More than I could have expected. I just need to go learn all this stuff now haha you have gave me some homework

Answer (score 0):

I kind of took the easy path out and just did the below

```
        imageView.setRotation(90);
```

So now the image displays correctly. I know it will probably cause me problems down the line but its the noobs dream.